# Сохранение файла в Pillow

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, pillow

В библиотеке Pillow есть функция save(). Она сохраняет картинку в ту же директорию, где и находится файл. Но что если мне нужно сохранять файл в другую директорию? Как мне её указывать?

Answer (score 1):

Ответ оказывается был очень легкий. Вместо обычного названия файла, нужно было указывать директорию.

```
img.save('C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\image.png')
```